# How to send data to a Symfony form from a page not generated by Symfony

Tags: symfony

My app built with Symfony 2 has a route `/getStarted`.

This route renders a form with only one field: the email.

Once the user enters the email, the app registers an account.

My app is hosted, say, at http://www.example.COM.

Now, I have set up the website (built with a CMS) for the app, but at the address http://www.example.NET.

**So, I want to set a form on http://www.example.NET (the CMS) that points to http://www.example.COM/getStarted (that is Symfony).**

The problem is that in Symfony I use the CSRF, so I cannot simply put the form's code in Wordpress because I don't have a fresh CSRF code.

Are there any possible ways to send data from http://www.example.net (a simple html page) to http://www.example.com/getStarted maintaining the csrf?

Maybe creating another `action`, something like an API? But how?

Same thing applies to login form, that I'd like to have on both sites, the .net and the .com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the CSRF you have to disable CSRF in your FormType->setDefaultOptions().
You add 'csrf_protection'   => false

```
$resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Registration',
        'csrf_protection'   => false
    ));
```

For the CORS you have many solution to do it. A great solution exist on symfony, it is [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle). I'm not sure of the code for your app but try to add it in config.yml

```
nelmio_cors:
paths:
    '^/getStarted':
        allow_credentials: true
        allow_origin: ['http://www.example.net']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution! I'll go deeper into it to understand if it does what I need... Also if I think it will! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the form doesn't handle any sensitive information (realted to user credentials etc.), you could simply disable CSRF on that single form. Otherwise you could embed the Symfony form in an iFrame on the Wordpress site - that way it will retain it's CSRF token.

Comment: I cannot disable the CSRF... :( The iframe solution maybe well, but maybe there is another solution...

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, you are trying to make cross-site request while protecting from them at the same time.